# how to pass hidden value to a form in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass an id value to my modal-form which is shown after clicking a particular button. 
Here is my code. Want to get teacher_id, subject_id and class_id for each teacher.
Here is a screen shot
[image]

```
[code]
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
       <h6 class="modal-title">Modal title</h6>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="myForm" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                <input type="hidden" name="teacher_id" value="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-label-group">
                        <select class="form-control" name="classes">
                              <option value="">Select Class</option>
                              <?php foreach($classes as $cl){?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $cl['class_id']?>"><?php echo $cl['class_title']?></option>
                              <?php }?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-label-group">
                        <select class="form-control" name="subjects">
                              <option value="">Select Class</option>
                              <?php foreach($subjects as $sub){?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $sub['subject_id']?>"><?php echo $sub['subject_name']?></option>
                              <?php }?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->

<script>
$('#btnSave').click(function(){
            var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
            var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
            //validate form
            var classes  = $('#classes option:selected').val(); 
            var subjects = $('#subjects option:selected').val(); 
            var result = '';
});
            $('#showdata').on('click', '.assign-class', function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('data');

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text('Assign Class');
            $('#myForm').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/teacher/update_teacher');
            $('#myForm').attr('input[name=teacher_id]').val(id) ;   
});
</script>
[/code]
```

I want to update teacher_id in myform.
Please somebody guide. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target hidden inputs like any other. It's only hidden to the viewer's eyes, not to Javascript's code. Use `$("input[name='teacher_id']")` to target it.

Answer (score 0):

You can select hidden targets like other targets, those hidden target are hidden for it's css atribute but it exists on DOM, just select element that you need like other element.

```
> $("input[name='teacher_id']")
```